# Size of the screen for graphic design

Tags: designers, color-reproduction, hardware-recommendation

I have a limited budget for a screen I'd use for my work in PS, Illustrator, Indesign. Mostly print publications, catalogs, folders, logos, vector/raster illustrations.

Would you go for a better quality, color accuracy - 23" 1920x1108 or a bit less fancy (quality-wise) but bigger 28" 3840x2160?

I'm just starting my professional life after being an intern in a graphic studio and I'd really appreciate your advice!

Comment: Color precision is must.

Comment: Save until you can get at least a 2500px wide display that is color accurate. Don't settle for those 4k "gaming" monitors and a 1920px wide monitor is going to "feel" small with today's software. The colors can be a problem with those "gaming" displays.

Answer (score 1):

I just start pointing this is my opinion and maybe someone can point one
that maybe better fits common sense, but I have a 4k basic 27" IPS monitor, and honestly, 4k, 2k for me are the same **while painting**. But for sure for letters and precise information on vectorized info it will make a lot of difference, I believe photo editing is the middle term, I've seen 4k photos that 1080p monitors lose details like full of star skys, etc.

> So you must see what is more relevant in your work...

I have no use for wide gamut monitors, most of my work is not intended for printing and even so I would need to figure if someone here in my city has a printer that can take relevant advantage of this, I mean, honestly I have zero experience with wide gamut, I'm not even sure it will result in any advantage on color proofing for "common place" printers or image edition.

> ...and at same time, what is honestly needed.

So I personally would go for a precise sRGB representation 4k monitor.

Comment: Thanks a lot for elaborating on this! My work will be  - I think - half and half, print and digital. So actually I would need something in between.

Comment: I would add that at last for me sRGB is a safe place, I really don't know why people use Wide Gamut, I suppose it is to have less  gamut warnings while soft proofing and so deliver a differentiated result with richer colors? Anyway I just like 4k because of area space and  better definition of letters and details, I majoritarily paint only and for this sRBG is just fine...

Comment: honestly if this bit less fancy is still a IPS and both show something like 99% sRGB get the bigger one, if the bigger one is a TN, I would absolutely not buy it.